# Fixed urdf object in Gazebo

Tags: gazebo, urdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I`m trying to get a fixed object in Gazebo, meaning it can not be moved by exerting forces on it. 
The urdf looks like this:

```
<link name="world"/>

<joint name="pallet_joint" type="floating">
    <parent link="world"/>
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
    <child link="pallet_body"/>
</joint>

<link name="pallet_body">
    <inertial>
        <mass value="10.0"/>
        <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
        <inertia ixx="1.0" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="0.1" iyz="0.0" izz="0.1"/>
    </inertial>
    <visual>
        <origin rpy="0 0 0 " xyz="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
            <box size="0.8 1.2 0.15"/>
        </geometry>
    </visual>
    <collision>
        <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
            <box size="0.8 1.2 0.15"/>
        </geometry>
    </collision>
</link>
```

The launch file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<launch>
    <param name="pallet" textfile="$(find gazebo_tests)/pallet.urdf" />
    <node name="spawn_pallet" pkg="gazebo" type="spawn_model" args="-urdf -param pallet -model pallet1 -x 5.0 -y 5.0 -z 0.5 " respawn="false" output="screen" />
</launch>
```

This works fine, but when I change the joint type to 'fixed' the pallet doesn't get spawned any more.

```
<joint name="pallet_joint" type="fixed">
```

Although 'pallet1' is displayed in the Models-list in Gazebo, it is no where to be seen. No errors get printed either. 
(Changing the joint type to 'continuous' makes the pallet shake around at the origin - not at location '5.0 5.0 0.5' where it should be spawned.)

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Regards, 
Eli

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11719/fixed-urdf-object-in-gazebo/) by [erkmns](https://answers.ros.org/users/1230/erkmns/) on ROS Answers with karma: 91 on 2011-10-27

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The previous answer did not solve the problem in my case, since the object could still be moved by exerting forces on it.

But following model file did the job for me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<model:physical name="pallet" 
    xmlns:body="http://playerstage.sourceforge.net/gazebo/xmlschema/#body"
    xmlns:geom="http://playerstage.sourceforge.net/gazebo/xmlschema/#geom"
>

<static>true</static>

<body:box name="pallet_body">
    <xyz>  0   0.0  0.0</xyz>
    <rpy>   0.0    0.0    0.0</rpy>
    
    <geom:box name="base">   
        <mesh>default</mesh>
        <size> 1.2 0.8 0.05</size>  
        <visual>
            <size> 1.2 0.8 0.05</size>
            <material>Gazebo/WoodPallet</material>
            <mesh>unit_box</mesh>
        </visual>
        <collision>
            <size> 1.2 0.05 0.5</size>
        </collision>
    </geom:box>
</body:box>

</model:physical>
```

Launch file as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<launch>
    <param name="pallet" textfile="$(find gazebo_tests)/pallet.model" /> 
    <node name="spawn_pallet" pkg="gazebo" type="spawn_model" args="-param pallet -gazebo -model pallet1 -x 0.0 -y -0.8 -z 0.15" output="screen" /> 
</launch>
```

---

Originally posted by [erkmns](https://answers.ros.org/users/1230/erkmns/) with karma: 91 on 2011-10-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [matthewmarkey](https://answers.ros.org/users/54103/matthewmarkey/) on 2020-05-18**:
Can anyone verify if this method of fixing a base link in the world frame is still supported?